# React Native iOS - How to add Provisioning Profile to ipa submitted to Appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-cli

I have finished my React Native application and the iOS version works properly on a simulator when I run: `npx react-native run-ios`

I then the follow the instructions on the documentation to create a release:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#3-build-app-for-release

I then looked for the .app file created by running:

```
npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release
```

I then created a folder called Payload and put the .app file inside and zipped it up.
After zipping the folder I changed the .zip extension to .ipa

When I submit the app to the Appstore I get the following errors:

> ERROR ITMS-90174: "Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a
>   provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision."

How to add Provisioning Profile to iOS release build in React Native?

Comment: use xcode to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to purchase the app store account by paying `$100` for an annual subscription then generate a `.certSigningRequest` file from your keychain and upload that file to the app store, Setup provisioning in your app store account for development or production environment which you want and download this profile from the app store.

Add this newly created provisioning profile to your Xcode project and then archives your project, It will create a `.ipa` file, either upload your archive with Xcode or export `.ipa` and upload manually to test flight or anywhere you want.

Here is a tutorial to set up your profile in Xcode.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWsjUBrn_IU

Comment: So ticking Automatically manage signing under Signing and Capabilities does not work for releases?

Comment: but sometimes it makes a problem so I prefer to set up a provisioning profile manually in the developer account.

Comment: Now I'm having problems with provisional profiles....I keep on getting: doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution....."  I have made a new question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343530/xcode-provisional-profile-doesnt-include-signing-certificate-apple-distributi