# Xcode Provisional Profile: doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution...."

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store, react-native-ios

I have made 2 certificates
The first one is of type "iOS Distribution".
The second one is of type "Distribution".

As far as I can remember, one of the steps of creating the second one was to choose "Apple Distribution" in the checklist as one of the steps to creating the certificate.

I have generated a Provisional Profile and added it to my Xcode and I keep on getting this error: `doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution MYNAME (ABCDEF)"`

So I go to the Provisional Profile section of `developer.apple.com` and edit the Profile to use the other certificate (therefore I have switched between the 2 certificates above for the same Profile) but I still keep on getting the same error: `doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution MYNAME (ABCDEF)"`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do?

Comment: try to change inside your Xcode >>build setting >>Signing >> code singing,  and change this setting to ios developer or some other.

Comment: I've played around with a few a few of the options there now and it is still not working...

Comment: Are you able to see your created certificate name in your Xcode?

Comment: yes I have downloaded it and double clicked it....

Comment: Is there any way to check what SIGNING CERTIFICATE is inside a provisioning profile???

Comment: The name you choose while making these profile it will be selected in xcode code signing.